# Tic tac toe multiple dimensions, how to find winner rows dynamically

Tags: ruby

In a 3x3 tic tac toe game, we know that the winner combinations are:

```
[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[2,4,6],[0,4,8]
```

I am wondering what would be the algorithm to find what the winner combinations are in any dimension tic tac toe. So imagine a method whose interface would be:

```
# dimension is a Fixnum
def winning_combinations(dimension)
end
```

What would be an idiomatic implementation in Ruby for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tic-tac-toe game I made in ruby:

https://github.com/Dbz/Tic-Tac-Toe/blob/master/Ruby/Tic%20Tac%20Toe.rb

I made functions `check_rows()`, `check_columns()`, `check_diagonals()`, and `check_winner()`.

I'm not sure what your definition of `dimension` is. Each one of the above functions is an algorithm to find out if there is a winning combination in a row, column, diagonal, or in general, but they take an array as a parameter, not an integer. If you want to turn each possible tic-tac-toe board into an integer with some sort of hashing function, then you could write your `winning_combinations(d)` function that returns true for the correct numbers. However, I do not believe that approach is dynamic.